# How can I perform a function for loop and output a sum in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, sum

I have an assignment that requires using a single "for" statement to calculate the manhattan and euclidian distances of two data sets. I'm also required to define the data sets and zip them as shown in the code. I'm very new to Python, and any tips on how to print the sum of the abs(x-y) function would be greatly appreciated!

I'd like the output to read "Manhattan Distance: 22.5"

Here is what I've tried

```
UserXRatings = [1,5,1,3.5,4,4,3]
UserYRatings = [5,1,5,1,1,1,1]    

for x, y in zip(UserXRatings, UserYRatings):
   print("Manhattan distance: ", abs(x-y))
```

Comment: What was the output? Why do you think it did that?

Comment: @PeterWood There is not an extra value, it just appears that way because on of the X coordinates is 3.5. Both coordinates have 7 values.

Comment: @zephyr Ah, sorry, I wasn't wearing my glasses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  What you're doing is printing the value of `abs(x-y)` each time through the loop.  You should probably store the sum of the values as you go through the loop, then print it once at the end:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> UserXRatings = [1,5,1,3.5,4,4,3]
>>> UserYRatings = [5,1,5,1,1,1,1]
>>>
>>> z = 0  # Initialize the variable to store the running total.
>>> for x, y in zip(UserXRatings, UserYRatings):
...     z = z + abs(x-y)  # Calculate the running total of `abs(x-y)`.
...
>>> print("Manhattan distance: ", z)
Manhattan distance: 22.5
>>>
```

Comment: Okay, I finally understand what's going on. Python evaluates the right side of the indented equation, z + the abs(1-5), then updates the left side to equal 4, and then repeats that on the right side with the 4 + abs(5-1) until we finally arrive at the sum which becomes the final value for z. I was having a hard time understanding how to use for statements, hopefully my a-ha moment will make sense to anyone that looks at this question in the future. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sum to get desired result-

```
print("Manhattan distance: ",sum(abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(UserXRatings, UserYRatings)))
#It should print - Manhattan distance:  22.5
```